# Off center center.x when working with stackview

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

[image]

I've got a stack view and I'm wanting when the user clicks on one of the buttons a little "bar" view centers underneath it (the view is outside of the stack view). I had this working before I layed out the buttons with autolayout by just setting

```
movableView.center.x = newView.center.x
```

and animating it. Now with the buttons in the stack view the movableView's center X does not line up with the buttons' center x's. It's like 1/3 way off centered.

The movable view itself has no autolayout on it.

What is the cause of this and how can I align the center x of views that have auto layout in play?

Comment: You could very easily use AutoLayout to align the views. An alternative way is to use a CALayer and add it as a sub layer of the stack view. Then update the frame of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without more information this is my best guess as to what the issue may be.

The `center` attribute is based on the view's `frame`, which means that it is using the superview (in this case the `UIStackView`) coordinate system.  If your `UIStackView`'s `frame.origin.x` is not at 0, which is how it appears in your screenshot, you will need to adjust your `movableView.center.x` accordingly.  This could be as simple as:

```
movableView.center.x = newView.center.x + stackView.frame.origin.x
```

Another option would be to convert the `center` to the main view's coordinate system, like this:

```
movableView.center.x = newView.convert(newView.center, to: self.view).x
```

Comment: The stackview's origin not being 0 was the issue, thank you so much! I probably would have never thought of that.

Comment: Good answer. (Voted). To the OP, always remember that every view's location is in it's parent view's coordinate system, not the screen coordinate system.Think of each view as a piece of graph paper with 0,0 at the upper left corner. A view's subviews are placed based on that 0,0 point, even when there are nested subviews.